# strptime incorrect output with input date

Tags: perl, datetime, datetime-format, strptime

I'm trying to convert a string into a dt object, as follows:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%A%m%d_%Y',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $string = 'Fri0215_2013';

print $strp->parse_datetime($string)->iso8601(), "\n";
```

When I run this, I keep getting `Fri02 is not a recognised day in this locale.` I looked at the strptime docs, and it says a local is an optional attribute of `strptime`, and `%A` or `%a% (tried both) should match the abbreviated day name, e.g. 'Fri',`%m% should match the month number, i.e. '02' and `_` obviously will match '_' (I hope!), and `%Y` will match the year including the century, i.e. '2013' Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `locale => 'en_EN'` to the constructor. If it works, the default locale your program inherits is probably for a language other than English.

Comment: @chepner that doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) generates for `%a%m%d_%Y` is:

```
/(\w+)([\d ]?\d)([\d ]?\d)_(\d{4})/
```

where `(\w+)` is supposed to capture the weekday name. The problem is that `\w` matches numbers as well, so for the string `Fri0215_2013` you get the following:

```
weekday name: Fri02
month: 1
day: 5
year: 2013
```

The code to generate the regex for weekday names is supposed to use a list of names for your locale but falls back to `\w+` because of a bug. I submitted a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=93863) so hopefully this gets fixed soon. [Update: It has been fixed in 1.55]

---

Workaround:

```
$string = s/^(...)(..)(..)_(....)/$1 $2 $3 $4/s;
```

and

```
pattern => '%a %m %d %Y'
```

Comment: How did you get that regex?

Comment: @AkshaiShah It's not a solution, it's a bug in DateTime::Format::Strptime.

Comment: Maybe `\pL` (letter) should be used instead of `\w`?

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. I was too busy tracking down the bug to get to the most important part: a solution!

Comment: @ikegami `%a%02m%02d_%Y` gives `Unidentified token in pattern: %0`. `\pL` would be the way to go, assuming no locales have numbers in the weekday names.